# opencv, pyinstaller. ошибка при запуске

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Здраствуйте. У меня есть простой скрипт, который делает фото с вебкамеры, и сохраняет в файл. Используется библиотека opencv.
Если я попробцю скомпилировать этот скрипт через pyinstaller, `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py`, то скрипт компилируется, но при запуске я получаю ошибку

`ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.`
[image: opencv]

python==3.9.0

opencv-python==4.5.4.58

pyinstaller==4.5.1

pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.3

Comment: Может, всё же убрать --onefile?

Comment: увы, это не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение!
Оказывается текущая версия opencv(4.5.4.58), не совместима с текущей версией pyinstaller, я установил предыдущую версию opencv(4.5.3.56), и оно заработало!

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56

#pip install pyinstaller==4.5.1
#pip install pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.3
```